# Beam json parsing

Tags: java, json, apache-beam

I am trying to read and parse JSON file in Apache Beam code.

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
options.setRunner(SparkRunner.class);

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

PCollection<String> lines = p.apply("ReadMyFile", TextIO.read().from("/Users/xyz/eclipse-workspace/beam-project/myfirst.json"));
System.out.println("lines: " + lines);
```

Below is the sample JSON that I need to parse `testdata` from this:
myfirst.json

```
{  
   “testdata":{  
      “siteOwner”:”xxx”,
      “siteInfo”:{  
         “siteID”:”id_member",
         "siteplatform”:”web”, 
         "siteType”:”soap”,
         "siteURL”:”www”
      }
   }
}
```

Could someone guide how to parse `testdata` and get content from the above JSON file and then I need to stream the data using Beam?

Comment: Still, I couldn't do this. If anyone could help, please share your ideas

Comment: May i use anyJSON library?

Comment: I am able to parse JSON content using JsonFactory and Jackson library. How to hand off this to Beam?

Comment: Okay, so before I can answer this question, can you please explain more about your input and output requirements? From what I can tell you have a nested json in your question. How do you want the output parsed string to look like? Because without that, you have too many possible answers that may not suit your requirements

Comment: Input is that JSON mentioned in the question. I want to parse “testdata" value and stream as string.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think that it is possible (or at least common) to process "pretty-printed" JSON. Instead JSON data usually ingested from [newline-delimited JSON](http://ndjson.org/), so your input file should look like following:

```
{"testdata":{"siteOwner":"xxx","siteInfo":{"siteID":"id_member","siteplatform":"web","siteType":"soap","siteURL":"www,}}}
{"testdata":{"siteOwner":"yyy","siteInfo":{"siteID":"id_member2","siteplatform":"web","siteType":"soap","siteURL":"www,}}}
```

After that, with your code in `lines` you have "a stream of lines". Next, you can `map` this "stream of lines" into "stream of JSONs", by applying parse-function in `ParDo`:

```
static class ParseJsonFn extends DoFn<String, Json> {

  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
    // element here is your line, you can whatever you want, parse, print, etc
    // this function will be simply applied to all elements in your stream
    c.output(parseJson(c.element()))
  }
}

PCollection<Json> jsons = lines.apply(ParDo.of(new ParseJsonFn()))  // now you have a "stream of JSONs"
```

Comment: Ok. Why parseJson is undefined for me? Do I need add right jar or import?

Comment: @Stella yes, you need to choose your JSON library: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/09/top-5-json-library-in-java-JEE.html. They all provide some variations of `parseJson` function.

Comment: Also getting this error : The method apply(PTransform<? super PCollection<String>,OutputT>) in the type PCollection<String> is not applicable for the arguments (ApacheBeamPrototype.ParseJsonFn)

Comment: Ok, for your sample code, which json library I have to choose? Jackson or ?

Comment: parseJson(c.element() is correct? It is still giving error as "The method parseJson(String) is undefined for the type ApacheBeamPrototype.ParseJsonFn"

Comment: Another point is, i want to stream the parsed testdata content, not JSON itself

Comment: cannot find the function parseJson. can you show your imports @chuwy

Comment: That is hypothetical function, @Ojasvsingh. Could be `io.circe.parser.parse` or `org.json4s.parse`.

Comment: @chuwy Oh... I thought you meant this https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/jackson/ParseJsons.html

Cannot find it either xD

Answer (score 0):

Yes, modern JSON libraries will let you parse a completely arbitrary stream of JSON and pseudo-JSON into a stream of objects, without having to load the whole file into memory.

There is no particular need to stuff your objects on a single line. Indeed, when designing software to process big data, it is good design practise to avoid reserving massive amounts of memory for batch processing your data, when on-demand streaming using mere kilobytes of memory would be possible.

Take a look at the short Baeldung tutorial: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api

I'll include the central parts of the Baeldung article code here, as it's good practise in case a site goes down:

```
while (jParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
    String fieldname = jParser.getCurrentName();
    if ("name".equals(fieldname)) {
        jParser.nextToken();
        parsedName = jParser.getText();
    }

    if ("age".equals(fieldname)) {
        jParser.nextToken();
        parsedAge = jParser.getIntValue();
    }

    if ("address".equals(fieldname)) {
        jParser.nextToken();
        while (jParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
            addresses.add(jParser.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the parser begins from a object start token, and proceeds to parse that object. In your case, you would want to keep looping until your file is done, so after you'd bailed out of this while loop, you'd keep moving forward until you find a `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`, then create a new object, go through this parsing routine, and in the end, hand off the object to Apache Beam.

Comment: Another point is, i want to stream the parsed testdata content using Beam

Comment: I am able to parse JSON content using JsonFactory and Jackson library. How to hand off this to Beam?